# Gmail | Google Play Service | Can't open an other application via URL Scheme when I sign in to Gsuit

Tags: android, google-play-services, gmail-api

I am integrating `Gsuite` with `JumpCloud`. However, I'm getting an issue with the Google Play Service and `Gmail` application when I sign in my `Gsuite` account.

Here is the sign-in workflow:
The user will add a new Google account from the setting app -> It will launch the Google Play Service application to display the sign in page.
After then, the page will redirect to the `JumpCloud` webpage for SSO authentification. From the SSO page, we need to open other application (such as: Google Play) by using `URL Scheme`. However, when the user clicks the `URL Scheme` to open other application, they receive an error message: `"ERR-UNKNOWN-URL-SCHEME"`

Could I know there is any issue with the `URL Scheme`? Is there any way to open the application from sign-in page on Google Play Service app?